# What does 'No Breakpoint' mean in this code

Tags: javascript, token

I ran this code using Chrome and had a look at the console (thank you for previous helps because I didn't know that I could do that!)  ..  *Unexpected token* - then when I click on that line... it says *no breakpoint*.

What is it talking about? (I have tried the code with and without a "!" in front of the window.confirm call)

```
If (window.confirm("Is that your final answer?")){
document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML = "The capital of Missouri is: <bold>" + capital + "</bold>, so says you.";
}
else{
return false;
}
```

Comment: Lowercase the `if`? "Unexpected token" is a syntax error, I don't think that "no breakpoint" when *clicking* on it has much do with that - it just tries to set a breakpoint in the code but is not able to.

Comment: Thank you.. Missing the Tree for the Forrest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your capital `If` to `if`:

```
if(window.confirm("Is that your final answer?")){    
  document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML = "The capital of Missouri is: <bold>" + capital + "</bold>, so says you.";
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. Missing the Tree for the Forrest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the "if(){}" statement can or should be capitalized here.

```
If(window.confirm(etc etc etc))
```

becomes

```
if(window.confirm(etc etc etc))
```

Comment: oh boo, zenith beat me to it

Comment: Thank you... Missing the Tree for the Forrest.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.confirm("Is that your final answer?")){

document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML = "The capital of Missouri is: <bold>" + capital + "</bold>, so says you.";
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
```